# designing three dimensional relationships with ORM (TypeORM)

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I tried to create a database schema with users, groups, documents and permissions.

- users can join multiple groups
- groups can have multiple users
- users can have permissions for documents
- groups can have permissions for documents
- permissions can be anything, not for documents only

I tried to create a small graphic for that

[image]

I started designing the entities

**User**

```
@Entity('User')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => GroupEntity, (group: GroupEntity) => group.users)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: GroupEntity[];

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => DocumentEntity, (document: DocumentEntity) => document.users)
  @JoinTable()
  documents: DocumentEntity[];
}
```

**Group**

```
@Entity('Group')
export class GroupEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => UserEntity, (user: UserEntity) => user.groups)
  users: UserEntity[];

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => DocumentEntity, (document: DocumentEntity) => document.groups)
  @JoinTable()
  documents: DocumentEntity[];
}
```

**Document**

```
@Entity('Document')
export class DocumentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => UserEntity, (user: UserEntity) => user.documents)
  users: UserEntity[];

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => GroupEntity, (group: GroupEntity) => group.documents)
  groups: GroupEntity[];
}
```

When it comes to the persmissions for documents you will see that the relation exists between 3 tables, users/groups, documents and permissions.

1. I use TypeORM for REST APIs (NestJs) and I'm not sure if a permission is an Entity. Due to the fact I'm designing REST endpoints this permission entity would be a shared entity along multiple endpoints.
2. How do I have to extend my entities for these permissions?

... and maybe you might come up with a better database design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is recomended to handle it manually, create an entity class  CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity and add a ManyToOne for each relation and on the other side on the Document, Group, User add a OneToMany Relation [here](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties) is an example of the use in ManyToMany with custom fields

Edit:

**User**

```
@Entity('User')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => GroupEntity, (group: GroupEntity) => group.users)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: GroupEntity[];

  @OneToMany((type: any) => CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity, (documentPermission: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity) => documentPermission.user)
  documentPermissions: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity[];
}
```

**Group**

```
@Entity('Group')
export class GroupEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => UserEntity, (user: UserEntity) => user.groups)
  users: UserEntity[];

  @OneToMany((type: any) => CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity, (documentPermission: CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity) => documentPermission.group)
  documentPermissions: CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity[];
}
```

**Permission**

```
@Entity('Permission')
export class PermissionEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany((type: any) => CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity, (userDocument: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity) => userDocument.permission)
  usersDocuments: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity[];

  @OneToMany((type: any) => CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity, (groupDocument: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity) => groupDocument.permission)
  GroupDocuments: CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity[];
}
```

**Document**

```
@Entity('Document')
export class DocumentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany((type: any) => CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity, (userPermission: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity) => userPermission.document)
  usersPermissions: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity[];

  @OneToMany((type: any) => CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity, (groupPermission: CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity) => groupPermission.document)
  GroupPermissions: CrossGroupDocumentPermissionEntity[];
}
```

**Cross_User_Document_Permission**

```
@Entity('Cross_User_Document_Permission')
export class CrossUserDocumentPermissionEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  permissionId: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  documentId: string;

  @ManyToOne((type: any) => UserEntity, (user: UserEntity) => user.documentPermission)
  user: UserEntity;

  @ManyToOne((type: any) => DocumentEntity, (document: DocumentEntity) => document.userPermission)
  document: DocumentEntity;

  @ManyToOne((type: any) => PermissionEntity, (permission: PermissionEntity) => permission.userDocument)
  permission: PermissionEntity;
}
```

Comment: @ Ralph thanks. So you would say Permission shouldn't be an entity?

Comment: No no I was refering to the three dimensional relation of the right instead of using the ManyToMany decorator create it manually with oneToMany ManyToOne you can have both three dimensional relations but @ManyToMany forces you to have only one table with two relations, if you need I can give you an example for the relation on the right

Comment: And about the permission if a user always have a group maybe you don't need the Cross_User_Document_Permission I beleive you need the Permission table because you can then diferenciate the permission unless you planning to use ACL in each document

Comment: a small example would be awesome :) it's possible that a user has no group membership